# Wordpress featured image on desktop only

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a mobile-first website that makes use of full-width background images which are uploaded to the page as featured images.

The problem I'm having is that the background images are styled inline because PHP is needed to get the actual background image. Now because they're being fetched inline, the images are going to be downloaded no matter what platform you're on. I only want the images to be available/downloaded if you're on a desktop/tablet device. NEVER on a mobile device. So I need a way that will stop the images from being downloaded if you're on a mobile device - has anyone any experience of achieving this before?

**The code I currently have:**

```
<?php $background_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page -> ID), 'full'); ?>

<div class="page-background-image" style="background-image: url(background_image);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#usage), which has WordPress support. Or you can use media queries in CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .page-background-image {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Media query has no effect because the call for the image is made inline so the image still gets downloaded.

Comment: @leaksterrr If that is an issue, then you should probably use a server-side solution such as Mobile-Detect.

Comment: I believe that if the div is not displayed, the image won't get downloaded - it is only downloaded when the image is supposed to be displayed, i.e. div is visible and background image is set.  In an opposite effect, I use divs right after my opening body tag to preload images for hover effects.

Comment: @CalvindeClaisse-Walford I think that this can depend on the browser: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: I had to wrap .page-background-image inside a parent container and then assign display:none; to the parent

Comment: @WayneWhitty Great article

Comment: @CalvindeClaisse-Walford Hopefully, browsers will learn to respect media queries a bit more in the future.